# Can a character-level Seq2Seq setup learn to perfectly reconstruct structured data like name strings?

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language

If not perfect, how well can they do? For example, if I give the Seq2Seq setup a name it did not see in the training process, can it output the same name without error?

```py
Example

name = "Will Smith"
output = DecoderRNN(EncoderRNN(name))
can_this_be_true = name == output
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some models which could quite easily learn an identity function, yes. Transformers would probably be the best choice.

> can it output the same name without error?

Probably nearly 100% of the time.

Comment: Thanks! Do you think the transformer architecture is capable of recognizing data format as well? For example, that "Will Smith" is <firstname lastname> and that "Smith, Will" is <lastname firstname>. I've tried doing this with simple Seq2Seq and it doesn't seem to perform very well.